# Laravel issue with security in profile page

Tags: angular, laravel, authentication, jwt, middleware

I have been having problems with my site in Laravel for some time. I have an Angular frontend and I'm using an api to query the specific user's data so that a specific user can change his data in his profile page. With that said, I obviously don't want unauthorized people to be able to go to other profile pages to change their data as well.

For example:
On my page, with the URL `.../user/1` the user can query his data. The problem with this is: If you change the `1` in `.../user/1` to `.../user/2` for example, the person can access to the data of the person with id `2`.

I tried following:
In my `api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

// Get Specific User
Route::get('user/{id}' ,'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getUserById')->middleware('auth');
```

Unauthorized users can no longer access the profile page, but all Authorized users can access all other users and change their data.

I also tried: `$id = Auth::id()`, but this returns me **Attempt to read property "id" on null**

The problem seems to me to be quite complicated, as I somehow need the id of the users currently logged in and make sure they can't access other users id. Do you have any idea how I could best do this?

I am using Laravel 8

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Thank you for the detailed answer, you gave me hope. I did everything as you described.

First I created with `php artisan make:middleware ResourceOwner` middleware and initialized it in the `Kernel.php` under **protected $routeMiddleware** like that:`'ResourceOwner' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\ResourceOwner::class,` and put in the function like you described.

But unfortunately, I get now **401 (Unauthorized)** no matters what ID I pass and with which user I am logged in. I tried:

```
1. auth('api')->user(); 
2. $request->user('api'); 
3. Auth::guard('api')->user()
```

But nothing of them worked. Do you have any idea what I am missing?
I also noticed that when I delete the function you described:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->id !== auth('api')->user->id) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I still get the same error **401 (Unauthorized)**.

But when I encode my JWT, I pass **user_id** as the ID, does that have anything to do with it?

But in my database my user is declared as **id** like: `$table->id();`. Unfortunately, I am still too inexperienced to say if this could have something to do with the error message. I use the **Tymon/jwt-auth package**.

Thanks again a lot for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using passport for authenticate?

Comment: No actually I am using the Tymon/jwt-auth package.

Comment: 1 - Remove the `ResourceOwner` middleware from `kernel.php`, otherwise you are explicitly saying that it must be used in every route.
2 - As per docs you can get your user by doing `auth()->user()` so I would try to get the id with `auth()->user()->id`

Comment: I removed it just now and I get following error: **"Target class [ResourceOwner] does not exist.** and a **Unauthorized** error. But when I use Postman I get following error: ** Route [login] not defined**. Can the problem be related to this?

Comment: When I delete the function inside **ResourceOwner.php** I still get the error **Unauthorized**, so I think the function can't even be called? But it's still confusing since the ```->middleware(['auth', 'ResourceOwner']);``` is defined after my route.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you need to add `use App\Http\Middleware\ResourceOwner;` in your route file to avoid `Target class [ResourceOwner] does not exist`. The `Route [login] not defined` is because your postman is not sending the `Accept: application/json` header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237730/discussion-between-luciano-and-xhtx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you should use `/users` routes in regards to users' CRUD and a `/profile` route for editing the user's data.

Anyway, there is a simple way to achieve what you need with middlewares.
Let's say that you want to allow to use a route ONLY if the `{id}` parameter is the same as the authenticated user.

You can create a very basic middleware IE `ResourceOwner`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ResourceOwner
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($request->id != $user->id) {
            abort(403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The middleware will check if the incoming `id` parameter is the same as the user logged in, if not, abort throwing a `403` error response.

In order to use this middleware, you can add it to your route

```
use App\Http\Middleware\ResourceOwner;

Route::get('user/{id}' ,'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getUserById')->middleware(['auth:api', ResourceOwner::class]);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your great answer and your time! I have edited my question, I would be very grateful if you could look in my question under **EDIT**.

Comment: Hello Luciano, it's me again. After our conversation, I sat down again for a few hours and finally found the problem. I just had to change in your function the condition **!==** to **!=** and then finally Postman handled it right. Thanks so much for your effort and time, rare to meet such a great man!

Comment: And the full function was like:     

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($request->id != $user->id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've updated my answer as per your final solution

Answer (score 1):

Authorization can be challenging but fortunately, Laravel comes with several tools to help you.

One of them is policies which allows you to control who can view/store/update/delete resources (like your users).

The full documentation about authorization covers this topic very well: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

---

That being said, for this specific case - the user - *you could* do something like `auth/me` that show the profile of the authenticated user (without passing the `id` as a parameter).

As always, there are many ways to do the same thing and in the end it all depends of your project, your experience, your goals...

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your time. You are right, I should look at the documentation again. As a beginner, I still find it quite difficult to understand this concept with authentication. I'll try my best!